# JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_CERT doesn't work when "SSLVerifyClient require" (setup on a directory-level)

Tags: tomcat, apache, mod-jk, mod-ssl

[My environment is this: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.2.9-2 mod_jk/1.2.31
(although we get the same behavior under an Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS with similar apache/mod_jk/tomcat specs)]

I have setup a virtual host for serving https and I want to have two types of directories/apps there: one served through 'plain' https and the other served with client authentication (with client certificates).

When "SSLVerifyClient require" is placed on the virtual host level, the relevant JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_CERT propagates the info to tomcat correctly. When it is placed on a directory level (inside the virtual host), it doesn't.
Any clues??

my httpd.conf includes the following lines:

```
...
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/mod_jk.shm"
JkLogFile     "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel    debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
...
```

where conf/workers.properties is just the following:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

and conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf contains the following lines:

```
Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/https"
    ServerName www.webrep.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@webrep.local
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/https-error.log"
TransferLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/https-access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/ssl/my-server.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/ssl/my-server.key"

SSLCACertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/ssl/ca/myCA.pem"

SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
Alias /examples/oneway/ "C:/https/oneway/"
<Directory "C:/https/oneway">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /examples/twoway/ "C:/https/twoway/"
<Directory "C:/https/twoway">
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth  10
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

JkMount  /examples/oneway/servlets/* worker1
JkMount  /examples/twoway/servlets/* worker1
JkExtractSSL Off
JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
JkEnvVar SSL_CLIENT_CERT

</VirtualHost>
```

On Tomcat I have just added a simple servlet outputting:

```
request.getAttribute("SSL_CLIENT_CERT")
```

under:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem isn't JkEnvVar, it's that, apparently, when JkMount and +Alias refer to the same URL, JkMount takes precedence and the directives inside  never come into effect (for example, try restricting access to the whole dir with 'Deny from All' - it never comes into effect; The servlets/jsps get accessed just fine).

Two solutions:

1) Use a  directive to control access for code that will run in Tomcat (i.e. mapped to Tomcat through JkMount).
2) Use 'SetHandler jakarta-servlet' instead of JkMount (see end of http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html for more). This works inside . I'm told that it also works inside , but I haven't checked this.

Hope this saves somebody the many hours we've spent here in order to solve this...

Comment: I have found that when a JkMount and a <Location/> both refer to the same URL, both appear to work. In my configuration I have a Location inside a VirtualHost :443 that raises the SSL bar (to require client authentication), and a JkMount for the same URL, and both work.